# NXP SmartMX Card Lifecycle Management

Tags: javacard, apdu, globalplatform, jcop

I have obtained a bunch of SmartMX dual interface cards from NXP, and have downloaded and setup JCOP Tools. While migrating my Java Card Applet from NetBeans to Eclipse has been rather easy, installing the compiled applet on the cards themselves has proved rather difficult. I can not select the Security Domain Applet on these sample cards. I believe this has something to do with the state the cards are in, as NXP has provided me with a *Transportation Key* and has strictly forbidden the cards to leave my premise without first being somehow *fused*. I have worked with ACS cards (ACOS3, namely) and guess these SmartMX cards are in a state of their lifecycle which does not allow applet upload and/or personalization. My problem is, I have been unable to find the documentation regarding JCOP lifecycle on NXP DocStore and the web. The only document which comes close to describing what I'm looking for is a PDF titled **GlobalPlatform Card Specification 2.2**, which says cards compatible with GP 2.2 have at least 5 different states: `OP_READY`, `INITIALIZED`, `SECURED`, `CARD_LOCKED`, and `TERMINATED`. That document does not specify the use of *Transportation Key*.

My question is, how does one use this *Transportation Key* to change the status of card from `OP_READY` to either `INITIALIZED` or `SECURED`?

Comment: Dear Mr.Biglari, May I have any phone number or email address of you? I have a problem and I think you can help me. Thanks (please mention me in your comment)

Comment: And another question, How you could register in NXP DocStore? I send the a request also,  "As you are from Iran, we can't let you to register.",they answered.

Comment: @User1-St I am no longer living in Iran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the transport key  as long as the card is not booted.
You should use the transportkey as AID in a SELECT by NAME command APDU.

It is possible to run the `/identify` in JCOP shell to see if card is fused or not
If the card is fused then the `/select [Transportkey]` will return with a status word indicating failure.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as possible. If the card is not fused, which commands are available after `/select TransportKey`?

Comment: you can change lots of things of the operating system, e.g. cardmanager keys. download the JCOP Administrator Manual from NXP DocStore for detailed information

Comment: After two days of searching the NXP DocStore, I give up. Can you please tell me in which category content I can find "JCOP Administrator Manual"?

Comment: Better ask NXP, really. The DocStore does not have the most comprehensive structure ever invented.

Comment: each JCOP version has its own administrator manual so the document is linked under Smartcard ICs with operating system->software->jcopxxx. if you dont have that folder ask your NXP product supporter